# Como posso fazer para imprimir apenas a parte fracionada do número

Tags: c

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como posso imprimir a parte fracionada do número real, ou seja, quando digito 5.678, gostaria de imprimir no segundo A(aonde esta o comentario), apenas o número 0.678, o que deveria usar para a impressão, não achei na math.h alguma que resolva o problema. Grato.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    float A;
    scanf("%f", &A);

    A = ceil(A);
    A = ;//Impressão nesta linha da parte fracionaria
    A = floor(A);

    printf("%f\n%.0f\n%f", A, A, A);


return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Note, porém, que o seu `printf` final não vai dar o resultado que você espera. Você usa *a mesma variável* pra armazenar valores diferentes, mas a sua saída vai ter o mesmo valor repetido três vezes (que será o valor da última atribuição à `A`, ou seja, o valor de `floor(A)`). Use variáveis diferentes para receber e armazenar os resultados das operações sobre `A`.

Answer (score 7):

Uma sugestão simples é fazer um *type casting* do número para um inteiro, e então subtrair esse valor inteiro do número original. Por exemplo:

```
printf("%f", A - ((int) A));
```

Assim, se o valor de `A` for `5.678`, a operação resultante será:

```
5.678 - ((int) 5.678) = 5.678 - 5 = 0.678
```

Comment: Luiz, seria interessante diante do que levantei no meta (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4083/8039) agregar a resposta do @pmg a sua, e corrigir também o código para que a resposta fique mais completa, o que acha?

Comment: Delfino, eu mesmo [já comentei](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59137/como-posso-fazer-para-imprimir-apenas-a-parte-fracionada-do-n%c3%bamero/59141?noredirect=1#comment121817_59137) sobre o problema adicional no código do AP. Mas como esse problema não tem a ver com a pergunta, eu não vejo por que editar a minha resposta para isso (dificilmente essa parte seria de ajuda a outra pessoa). A resposta do colega @pmg é util ao AP, mas na minha opinião ele (o pmg) faria bem em complementar tal como sugerido pelo bfavaretto lá no Meta (até porque assim deixaria de merecer o seu -1) :)

Answer (score -1):

Vais alterando o valor de `A` no teu codigo

```
    // digamos que o utilizador digitou 5.678
    A = ceil(A);                    // A passou a 6
    A = ;          // a parte fracionaria de 6 'e 0
    A = floor(A);                   // A passou a 6
```

Sugiro que arranjes outras variaveis

```
    // digamos que o utilizador digitou 5.678
    B = ceil(A);                    // B passou a 6
    C = ;                           // ??
    D = floor(A);                   // D passou a 5
```

Comment: Não responde a pergunta, deveria estar como comentário.

Comment: Perfeitamente de acordo, @Delfino ... mas nao me pareceu que o formato dos comentarios fizesse esta nota compreensivel.

Comment: concordo @pmg, vou levar tal questão ao meta, pois realmente eu não sei qual é o melhor, porém entendo que não seja uma resposta. :)

Comment: abri no meta com o intuito de amadurecermos tal questão e quem sabe sugerir melhoras no mecanismo de comentário, ou quem sabe definir como boa prática editar diretamente a pergunta e assim corrigir o código: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4082/8039